# SQL Server Logon Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have problem a piece of shipping software. I have one query to pull up order info(ie name address, order number), one to pull up the items. Then I have one to find the rates based on weight and zone. I cannot log in to that last query. Every time I hit that query I get a log in failed. 
My question is why is that query failing?

Here is the method I am calling my query with:

```
    private void pscost(int billedweight)
    {
        RateBLL r = new RateBLL();
        AmazonProShipDataSet1.uspsDataTable u = r.USPSrate(billedweight);
        foreach (AmazonProShipDataSet1.uspsRow row in u)
        {...
        }
     }
```

Here is the BLL:

```
   [System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodAttribute
   (System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodType.Select, false)]
    public AmazonProShipDataSet1.uspsDataTable USPSrate(int weight)
    {
        return USPS.USPS(weight);
    }
```

The table I am query was add after the first two table where and they are in the same SQL Server express db. The error message is Log In failed could not authenticate. From Untrusted domain.

Comment: Do you have some code to show us? And a more descriptive error message.

Comment: Would you provide the error message you have got ..

Comment: Check the difference in your code in the connection code between a query that works and one that doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`log in failed` has nothing to do with your query executing.  You need to ensure that the login you are actually using is valid.  If you're getting that message, then your client is able to see the database and is trying to connect, but it can't authenticate.  You need to check your underlying permissions.

Without being able to see your code, it makes it difficult to debug -- and most of it's guessing.  I would assume, there is something happening with the actual connection between the first and second query.  Are you changing databases, authentications, permissions?

Comment: I posted some code. It is a newly added table on the same db. I gave the user ever permission I could, and have all the pipes enabled.